# How tags are used for the "cross out" format?

Tags: support, tags, formatting

I know how to bold and italicise, but not cross out (line through text).

[See mattdm's answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/50536/whats-the-difference-between-colour-space-and-bit-depth) of "life" and "chololates".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>Like this.</strike>... (Use < strike > stuff < /strike >.)

Comment: Oh, strike... How come that's not in help?

Comment: It's in the markdown editing help when you have the editor open, but it is listed under the HTML section.

Comment: I see. That<strike>'s intuitive</strike> makes sense.

Comment: And also, as you see, not all features are supported in the reduced syntax used in comments. :)